# How can I shorten this to 1 line?

Tags: javascript, date

I want to change my below three lines to just one line.

```
const date = todayDate(); //console-log: 2023-11-4
const timesasaddastamp = Date.parse(date);
const businessDayDate = new Date(timesasaddastamp); // console-log: Sat Nov 04 2023
```

How can I shorten this?

I tried doing:

```
const businessDayDate = new Date.parse(date);
```

Comment: what is `todayDate()`? What is your expected outcome.  But generally you can always transform something like `let a = A(); let b = B(a); let c = C(b)` into `let c = C(B(A()))`;

Comment: Why? Just because you can do something does not mean it's a good idea. If *todayDate* returned a format supported by ECMA-262 like "2023-11-04", then `new Date(todayDate())` will suffice. But it will parse the date as UTC, not local which may or may not be important.

Answer (score 1):

If you want today in form of Sat Nov 04 2023, you can simply write this:

```js
const businessDayDate = new Date();
```

Else, you can write like this:

```js
const businessDayDate = new Date(Date.parse(todayDate()));
```

Comment: `new Date()` returns a date object, not a string like "Sat Nov 04 2023". The use of *Date.parse* in `new Date(Date.parse(todayDate()))` is redundant. The OP format "2023-11-4" is not supported by ECMA-262 so parsing is implementation dependent. It returns an invalid date in Safari at least.

Answer (score 0):

The following oneliner will return the date in the required format i.e., 'Sat Nov 04 2023'

```js
console.log(new Date().toDateString());
```